# check atleast three options is selected on form submission in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactjs, I am using `ant.design` selection module to select different skill from drop down. I want to check atleast three options is selected on form submission. I will also share code with you Can you guys help me how I can solve this problem

```
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('skills', {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please select skillset!',
              },
            ],
          })(
            <Select
              mode="tags"
              style={{ width: '100%' }}
              defaultValue={defaultSkills}
            >

              {children}
            </Select>,
          )}
        </FormItem>
```

Comment: You can maintain count of selected options in a state and check if it is more than 2.

Comment: Jon, will be helpful if you can add your entire component, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if antd has a built-in feature like that but you can always check your state on formsubmit event. Bind the this element to state and check this state  on form submit event, if the selected option count is less then 3, do what you want.

Comment: @umki Could you please write code for validation.

Comment: @TusharKotlapure Could you please give me example

Comment: here is example https://codesandbox.io/s/4x48v2lvx

Comment: Please visit this link and if it possible please solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `antd`, there is an option for multi selection :     `mode="multiple"` then you will have a array of selected values in your handleChange method which you can check whatever conditions you need. Here is an example :

```
const Option = Select.Option;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

function handleChange(value) {
  // Value is a array of selected values ["a10", "f15", "g16"]
  console.log(value); 

  // Do rest of your code here
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    placeholder="Please select"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    {children}
  </Select>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pk6nmk560